# Does a series resistor limit power consumption?

Tags: resistors, raspberry-pi, low-power

I have a magnetic reed switch connected between two pins of a Raspberry Pi. As far as I'm aware, the Pi can handle a short circuit between two of it's GPIO pins, so having nothing except the reed switch is completely fine. I've heard something about the maximum current of an input pin being 16 mA. My setup doesn't need that much current to do its thing, so I was wondering how I could save power by limiting the amount of current that comes out of the corresponding output pin. Putting a resistor in series with the reed switch would limit the current, and I first thought that this would save power as well, but someone pointed out to me, that the power saved could just be lost as heat, making no difference at all.

Essentially, what I'm asking is this: Can you save power by putting a resistor in series? If not, how would one go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: A gpio input pin takes very little current under normal conditions, so a resistor will make very little difference. Tell us (edit your question)  what you are trying to achieve with this, there may be a better way.

Comment: @RoyC There's not much to add. The only thing of relevance in my circuit is this reed switch, which I'm using to monitor the state of a door.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

16mA would not be input current, it would be the maximum output current of the output pin, while still being within logic level specs. Most likely short circuit current is even higher than 16mA. An input pin draws virtually no current, except when there is a weak pull-up or pull-down resistor enabled.

You can save power only if you accidentally setting both pins as outputs, and short circuiting them while one is high and the other low. But for normal use where you have a digital input with weak pull resistor enabled, a series resistor is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer your original question: Yes, a resistor does limit power output of a voltage source. Lets say you have a circuit with 1000 equivalent Ohms on a 10V voltage source. You will observe 10mA of current, this means 100mW of power. Now put in an additional 1000Ohm Resistor and your current will drop to 5mA. You still have 10V over both resistors, so the total power consumed ends up at 50mW.
Of course you cant just limit current and expect everything to work. Usually a circuit will draw as much current as it needs. For your application this is certainly no problem to consider.

Comment: Thanks, but I have one more question. I understand that some energy gets lost as heat through the resistor. Is there a way to calculate that?

Comment: @Nik Tedig Yes: Look for "Power Dissipation". But it's not relevant for CMOS applications which use very little current and are more dependant on the voltage level. Energy loss through a resistor or equivalent is important when you want to reduce the voltage, by limiting the current, to power something from a higher voltage source.

Comment: Sorry for not answering, havent been on stackexchange a lot. Power dissipated in a resistor is the voltage dropping over it times the current flowing through it. Be wary of correct calculation of voltage. If you have 2 resistors of same value in series for example, each will have half of the total voltage drop.

If you want to know more I would advise you to take a basic electronics course.That will help you understand more clearly than asking specific questions will.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your question about current and power when connnecting device output pins to device input pin.

> so having nothing except the reed switch is completely fine.

You do not provide a schematic, but it sounds as though you have a reed switch between an output pin and an input pin, and nothing else connected to that input pin.

So you are not surprised by the results if/when you build this circuit, you should be aware of what happens when an input pin is not connected to any stable voltage source, for example by being disconnected by a switch. Typically, the voltage at a floating input pin will rise to a logic 1 state. Forewarned is forearmed.

Comment: Interestingly enough, putting a pull up/down resistor in doesn't do anything in my case. Regardless of if I have a pull up/down resistor, the value always oscillates regularly between on and off. Maybe this has something to do with the attraction of the two leads inside of the reed switch?

Comment: If your input oscillates between on and off for 500mSec or less, it is probably contact bounce. If you input oscillates continuously, without stopping, your pull up or pull down resistor may have too large a value.

Comment: It oscillates way faster than 500mSec and every second or so it stays open for a little longer than usual, then it goes back to regular oscillation. The output kind of seems like it gathers energy over the small bounces and then releases it for one big bounce and then goes back to bouncing by tiny amounts. Im using the built in resistors in the Raspberry Pi, I can try to use weaker resistors, but it seems to me as if the problem is within the reed switch itself. Or maybe I'm driving it wrong. My output pin is 3.3 volts and like I said the max current draw is 16mA to my knowledge.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding a schematic. There is a schematic editor as one of the tools above the edit box.